# Hp pavilion dv600 low battery signal randomly with AC plugedin

Tags: power

Pavilion DVD 600 battery is low but I have been working it with  its AC adaptor without any problem. Now, after some time, battery low warning comes on and the laptop shuts down even with AC plugged in. I have checked the adaptor output voltage. It is exactly as per specs. The machine is not running hot either.

Comment: Does the battery charging indicator show up (either led on the case, or as a icon in the panel near the clock(This if you are using Windows)? Could be a broken leg on the motherboard for the port where the charger connects to the lap top.

Comment: Thank you Carl. Another observation is that the longer the laptop is powered off, the longer it takes for the problem to reappear. With the AC power remaining plugged in, if I power off overnight, the following morning it gives no trouble for a couple of hours. Does it suggest a 'broken leg'?